# JDBC templates with Plpgsql Functions returning wrong value?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql, spring-jdbc

In our database we currently have the following function declared (table names and parameters have been changed to protect the foolish :) )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_foo(i INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS '
    DECLARE value INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT next_foo INTO value
        FROM status_table
        WHERE status=i
        FOR UPDATE;

        UPDATE status_table
        SET next_foo=(value+1)
        WHERE status=i;

        RETURN value;
    END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then later on in our java server code, we have the following:

```
private int getNextFoo(int status) {
         return jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("SELECT next_foo(?)", status);
   }
```

However, what seems to be happening as that the return value is 1 higher than it should be. Calling the function from the psql commandline causes things to behave as expected, however making the call through JdbcTemplates seem to increment the return value, instead of giving the current value and increment the one in the table.

So, as an example, if **foo** has a starting value of **100**, the jdbc call is bringing back **101** instead of **100**. The status_table is getting updated appropriately, but the inital value coming back is worng.

Am I missing something boneheaded in my plpgsql function? Or is there some odd behavior regarding stored procedures with jdbc templates that I'm missing here?

Comment: While it doesn't explain directly, why not just use `update ... set ... returning ...`?

Comment: @CraigRinger We actually did end up doing that, but I'm more curious now on what was happening with the function than anything else.